# FastAPI endpoint returning "unprocessable entity" [Err code: 422]

Tags: python, mysql, fastapi

I have a little knowledge of Python and was trying to build a simple backend using `FastAPI` it is a `GET REQUEST` that returns a user from a `PhpMyAdmin` MySQL Database. Running the endpoint on Postman returns `ERROR 422`.
What is exactly causing this issue? and what are the possible fixes?

this is my code so far:

here's the

```
#main.py
from typing import List
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
import dbhelper
import models
import schemas
from database import SessionLocal, engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

models.myBase.metadata.create_all(bind = engine)

app = FastAPI()

def getDatabase():
    database = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield database
    finally:
        database.close()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "server live"}

@app.get("/user/{id}", response_model = schemas.User)
def fetch_users(userId: int, database: Session = Depends(getDatabase)):
    user = dbhelper.getUser(database, userId)
    if user is None:
        print("User not found")
    return user
```

this is the models.py:

```
#models.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from database import myBase


class User(myBase):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String(64))
    email = Column(String(64))
    role = Column(String(10))
```

now here's schemas.py

```
#schemas.py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class UserBase(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[int]
    username: str
    email: str
    role: str

class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    username: str
    email: str
    role: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

this is the database config. file (I am trying to connect in a phpmyadmin mysql database)

```
#databse.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

DATABASE_URL = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:@localhost:3309/forma"

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

myBase = declarative_base()
```

now this is where I build my CRUDs:

```
#dbhelper.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
import models


def getUser(db: Session, userId: int):
    return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == userId).first()
```

When I run postman the results I get are:

> STATUS: 422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY

and the error message is the following:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "query",
                "userId"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

As proposed below I fixed the path variables from "`/{id}`" to "`/{userId}`" and now Postman returns `ERR 500: Internal Server Error` and the server log:

> File ".\main.py", line 27, in fetch_users
> user=dbhelper.getUser(database, userId)
> File ".\dbhelper.py", line 7, in getUser
> return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == userId).first()
> raise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: relationship 'userId' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>)

Comment: so HTTP 422 is the error reported to the client, what does the server log says?

Comment: @HernanGarcia this is what I've got `127.0.0.1:50024 - "←[1mGET /user/1 HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m422 Unprocessable Entity←[0m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining endpoint like this:

```
@app.get("/user/{id}")
def fetch_users(userId: int):
```

You are using `id` as a url substitute but function parameter name is `userId`. This should work:

```
@app.get("/user/{userId}")
def fetch_users(userId: int):
```

Comment: this seems like going on the right track, however, now postman returns `ERR 500` and the server log returns the following response: `File ".\main.py", line 27, in fetch_users
    user=dbhelper.getUser(database, userId)
  File ".\dbhelper.py", line 7, in getUser
    return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == userId).first()`and `raise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: relationship 'userId' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>)`

Comment: @ThorvaldOlavsen but it is working for me though by just changing the line (`id` > `userId`)

Comment: @thorvaldolavsen in my opinion you should ask another questino on that error

Comment: actually, you were right and your solution worked perfectly fine, I was returning a (print) instead of an Object! that's what you get after 6 hours of non stop coding!! thank you for taking time!